# Getting state of element in angular 4

Tags: angular, angular-ng-if

Basic question on angular binding

```
<input type="checkbox" aria-selected="false" name="test">

<input name="user" *ngIf="?">
```

can i bind/listen to element "test", when check box is selected input element "user" should be enabled. 
what should go into ngIf condition. can this be done without using ngmodel binding

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using reference:

```
<input type="checkbox" aria-selected="false" name="test" #checkbox>
<input name="user" *ngIf="checkbox.checked">
```

Although, chances are that `checkbox.checked` will not be updated, after you change checkbox state. Then try something like this:

```
<input type="checkbox" aria-selected="false" name="test" #checkbox ngModel>
<input name="user" *ngIf="checkbox.checked">
```

Answer (score 1):

One possible solution:

```
<input #myCheckbox type="checkbox" aria-selected="false" name="test">

<input name="user" *ngIf="myCheckbox.checked">
```

But this will remove the second `input` from the DOM completely. Maybe do this to really disable the `input`:

```
<input name="user" [disabled]="!myCheckbox.checked">
```

Comment: `*ngIf` won't hide the input, it will remove it completely from the DOM